# Tableviewcell isn't changing background image

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Note this code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentTableViewCell
    cell.commentText?.text = comments![indexPath.row]
    if let objectId = yak?["user"].objectId {
        let commentor = commentorIds[indexPath.row]
        if commentor == objectId {
            cell.commentText.textColor = UIColor(red: 136.0/255, green: 135.0/255, blue: 134.0/255, alpha: 1)
            let image = UIImage(named: "eh")
            cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: image?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 50, right: 50)))
        } else {
            cell.commentText.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            let image = UIImage(named: "whatsthatnow")
            cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: image?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 100)))
        }
    }
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    //cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "goodbg"))
    return cell
}
```

This works quite well for a specific view controller, however. Note this code snippet.

```
func tableViewOld(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    let image = UIImage(named: "eh")
    cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: image?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 50, right: 50)))
```

This same code doesn't work for some reason on another cell. I can't seem to find a reason for it, so I was hoping one of you guys could spot something I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Check the .h file Of UITableViewCell.  I found this.

Default is nil for cells in `UITableViewStylePlain`, and non-nil for `UITableViewStyleGrouped`. The `backgroundView` will be added as a subview behind all other views.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *backgroundView;
```

Normally, we don't do any suggest:

1. Add an `ImageView` to Cell.
2. Set `ImageView`'s frame equal `cell.contentView.bounds`
3. Control it's behavior by your self.
4. Do what you wanna do!